# wiki is currently unable to handle this request

Tags: php, mediawiki, mediawiki-extension

I need to show mathematical terms in `mediawiki-1.26.2` so I tried to install [SimpleMathJax](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:SimpleMathJax) on mediawiki. I followed the described in extension page:

1. I downloaded `SimpleMathJax-master.zip` then extract, rename it to `SimpleMathJax` and move it to `extensions` directory of `mediawiki`.
2. I added these lines to `LocalSettings.php`:

   # End of automatically generated settings.
    # Add more configuration options below.
    require_once "$IP/extensions/SimpleMathJax/SimpleMathJax.php";
    $wgSimpleMathJaxSize = 120;

But when I wnat to browse to the Wiki, I get this error:

```
wiki is currently unable to handle this request.
```

Also I tried to replace `require_once "$IP/extensions/SimpleMathJax/SimpleMathJax.php";` line with `wfLoadExtension( 'SimpleMathJax' );` but problem remains.

Answer (score 0):

See the [debugging manual](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:How_to_debug) on how to find out what your error is.

Answer (score -1):

your using require_once wrong, you are using it with just quotes but you are supposed to use brackets 

`require_once ("$IP/extensions/SimpleMathJax/SimpleMathJax.php");`

I don't know if that will fix the problem, but it could be something as simple as it! :)

Comment: This is incorrect. `require_once` is a language keyword and can be used with or without braces.